# What exactly are language views?

Tags: plutus, nami-wallet

I read the docs for `language views` here, but I still don't quite understand what they are: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger-specs/blob/master/eras/alonzo/test-suite/cddl-files/alonzo.cddl#L97

For the Spacebudz marketplace, Alessandro requires this to be set and I'm not sure if it we need to change it for our own dApp: https://github.com/Berry-Pool/spacebudz/blob/main/src/cardano/market/languageViews.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [explanation follows](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger/blob/master/eras/alonzo/test-suite/cddl-files/alonzo.cddl#L111-L114) after the canonical encoding description

```
; For PlutusV1 (language id 0), the script integrity data is a cost_model.
; This is the value of the costmdls map at key 0.
```

Looks like you need to encode cost-model map as language-views key `0` according to [canonical encoding](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger/blob/master/eras/alonzo/test-suite/cddl-files/alonzo.cddl#L100-L109).